# QM Momentum operator in spherical coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, integration

As part of a calculation, Ballentine (Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development page 295) uses the following device:
$$\langle \psi | \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{P} |\psi \rangle = (\langle \psi | \mathbf{P}) \cdot (\mathbf{P} |\psi \rangle) = \hbar^2 \int dV \left|\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} \right|^2.$$
It is this last step which confuses me. Obviously, he is inserting position space completeness, but where have the angular parts of $\mathbf{P}$ gone here?

Comment: If this is in spherical coordinates, why is there a $\mathrm d^3 r$?

Comment: It's poor notation but it means a volume element in his notation. I will amend. BTW, does this count as homework? It's just something that came up in the main text? @TobiasFünke

Comment: Can you give a definition of $\mathbf P$ then?

Comment: $\mathbf{P}$ is the 3D generator of translations (a vector operator with its usual expansion in Cartesian coordinates)? @TobiasFünke

Comment: Are you ***sure*** *ψ* is not simply taken to be a radial function, so the angular derivatives vanish applied to it??

Comment: I am quite confused. Knowing what I know about the Laplacian operator in 3D, I think that even for a plausibility test I would be looking for $\left|\partial_r(r\psi)\right|^2$, and the angular parts already integrated away. By this, I mean that the old $\psi^*\frac1{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_r\psi)$ is somewhat symmetrically converted to $\frac1{r^2}\partial_r(r\psi)^*\partial_r(r\psi)$ and the $\frac1{r^2}$ cancels with the volume element's $r^2$. We might need to see way more context to determine what is actually happening.

Comment: Presumably Ballentine means to write: $\langle \psi| P^2|\psi\rangle = \int dV \left|{\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \vec r}}\right|^2$, where $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec r}$ is also known as the vector $\vec \nabla$. There is generally no way to just remove all the angular dependence.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Oy, I think that's it. This occurs at the top of page 295 in Ballentine, and he is indeed assuming a spherically-symmetric $\psi$. Thank you for pointing this out. I suppose this result then makes sense right, since $\theta$ and $\phi$ derivatives vanish when we apply the position space representation $\langle \mathbf{x}|\mathbf{P}|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar\left(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}\mathbf{\hat{r}}\right)$ in this spherical $\psi$ limit? Incidentally, isn't there a problem in expanding the position and momentum operators in non-Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @CosmasZachos You are absolutely right. I forgot that earlier in the example Ballentine had taken a trial wavefunction with spherical symmetry. My apologies for the error.

Comment: @hft Please see other comments here -- it was my mistake. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from Question Post:]

> As part of a calculation, Ballentine (Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development page 295) uses the following device:
> $$\langle \psi | \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{P} |\psi \rangle = (\langle \psi | \mathbf{P}) \cdot (\mathbf{P} |\psi \rangle) = \hbar^2 \int dV \left|\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} \right|^2.$$
> It is this last step which confuses me. Obviously, he is inserting position space completeness, but where have the angular parts of $\mathbf{P}$ gone here?

[Quoting from comments now:]

> Oy, I think that's it. This occurs at the top of page 295 in Ballentine, and he is indeed assuming a spherically-symmetric ψ
> . Thank you for pointing this out.

We have:
$$\langle \psi | \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{P} |\psi \rangle = \hbar^2 \int dV \left|\vec \nabla \psi \right|^2,\tag{1}$$
where we are now considering the proper vector operator expression for $\vec P$ in the position basis: $\vec P \to -i\hbar \vec\nabla$.

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) that in spherical coordinates $\vec \nabla$ can be written as:
$$
\vec \nabla = \hat r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\hat \theta}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}
+\frac{\hat \phi}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi}\;.
$$

However, per the quoted comment, the wavefunction $\psi$ is spherically symmetric, so our expression for nabla can be replaced with:
$$
\vec \nabla \psi \to \hat r \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}\;,
$$
whereby our Eq. (1) above reduces to Ballentine's page 295 equation.